# use c# query mongodb document field values

Tags: c#, mongodb

In my C# console application project I'm using MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3 with connection to MongoDB 3.2.10.

I have documents in collection which I output to console with the code below:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f034bf5c57ef10bc4f8d3d"), "firstname" : "Christano", "birthdate" : ISODate("1995-04-14T02:32:31Z"), "country" : "Brazil" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f0c7bb5c57ef10bc506216"), "firstname" : "Pele", "birthdate" : ISODate("2007-05-14T02:32:31Z"), "country" : "Brazil" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f0ca995c57ef10bc506763"), "firstname" : "Anthony", "birthdate" : ISODate("2010-04-14T02:32:31Z"), "country" : "Italy" }

How can I write the individual field values to the console so I can store and manipulate those values individually?

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

var playerfirstname;
var playerbirthdate;
var playercountry;

var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var DB = client.GetDatabase("football");
var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("players");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("country", "Brazil");
var cursor = collection.Find(filter).ToCursor();
foreach (var document in cursor.ToEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine(document);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should define a class like the following

```
internal class Player
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

and then change the collection type as below:

```
var players = DB.GetCollection<Player>("players");
```

Then applying just LINQ you can filter out all the players whose country isn't the Brazil and access the properties of each player as below:

```
var playersInBrazil = players.AsQueryable()
                             .Where(player => player.Country == "Brazil");

foreach(var playerInBrazil in playersInBrazil)
{
    Console.WriteLine(playerInBrazil.FirstName);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting Error CS1061 'IMongoCollection<Program.Player>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'IMongoCollection<Program.Player>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' ConsoleApp1

Comment: @ikask please check my update and let me know. Thanks

Comment: now I'm getting.. 
Error CS1061 'Program.Player' does not contain a definition for 'Country' and no extension method 'Country' accepting a first argument of type 'Program.Player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ikask `Country` should be renamed to `country` in the lambda expression we pass to the `Where` method.